# MySql could not restore whole dump file

Tags: mysql, restore, dump

MySql cluster is unable to restore whole dump file. Error:

> MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations and increase MaxNoOfAttributes

This is the command I tried:

```
mysql -u username -p create database databasename; use databasename; source /path/to/dump/file;
```

While restore dump sql it says increases MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations in some tables and increase MaxNoOfAttributes in some tables so out of 320 tables restore only store 50 tables, rest tables are not restore with above error.

Comment: How's your disk space?

Comment: disk space is more than sufficient its 1TB and dump sql is of 114MB

Comment: its dump sql engine=ndb and restore engine=ndb
but why it says increase MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations and increase MaxNoOfAttributes
it has 32GB of RAM
without editing ndb config file . how to increase those two values from mysql root

Comment: anyone could help me with this error, what could be the process to restore all tables of the database
or any idea to migrate live mysql database  from one to another server in linux (centos 7)

Comment: if i change dump file engine=innodb and restore it will restore all tables but my engine is changed what to do in future to add or alter the database

Comment: What is the reason for using NDB?

Comment: yes , if i try to restore in same engine=ndb then there is error, i have no idea how to restore full tables of that database into mysql cluster/engine=ndb.

Comment: [ndb_mgmd default]
# Directory for MGM node log files
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
[ndb_mgmd]
#Management Node db1
HostName=ip
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=2     
DataMemory=1024M  IndexMemory=512M    # Memory allocate for index storage
###Directory for Data Node
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=100000
MaxNoOfLocalOperations=110000
MaxNoOfAttributes=10000
ODirect=1
MaxNoOfTables=20320
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=2048
MaxNoOfUniqueHashIndexes=2048
[ndbd]
[ndbd]
[mysqld]
[mysqld]
##################
Any solution to this problem